# View Controller Animation in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I need to animate a view when user click on the button. i am using the following code for animating

App Delegate

```
ViewController2 *vc2_controller = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *baseViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc2_controller];
    [self.window addSubview:baseViewController.view];
     self.window.rootViewController = vc2_controller;



    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];  

    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];


    self.viewController = [[vc1controller alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

//ViewController1.m -- This is Working

```
[self.navigationController pushSlideViewController:self.navigationController];
```

I created function definition inside the category
//Category

```
- (void)pushSlideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   // NSLog(@"In Navigation Controller");

    //[UIView transitionWithView:viewController.view duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:nil completion:nil];
    CGRect screensize = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        NSLog(@"In View ANimatin");
        CGRect current_rect =  viewController.view.frame;
        viewController.view.frame = current_rect;
        current_rect.origin.x = screensize.size.width-50;
        viewController.view.frame = current_rect;

    }];

}
```

Now i am calling ViewController1.m from ViewController2.m  -- Animation is Not Working

```
ViewController1 *view_control = [[ViewController1 alloc]init];

[self.navigationController popSlideViewController:view_control];

//Category
-(void)popSlideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    CGRect screensize = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    //NSLog(@"In Pop");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        //View is not coming to original position.
        CGRect current_rect =  viewController.view.frame;
        NSLog(@"In View ANimatin %f",current_rect.origin.x);
        viewController.view.frame = current_rect;
        current_rect.origin.x = 0.0;
        viewController.view.frame = current_rect;

    }]; 
}
```

Note: i am not using ios5 :-)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You're loading VC2 from VC1, which, as you say, works fine. Then you're trying to load VC1 from VC2, which is where the problem lies - VC1 is still loaded, behind VC2, so you just need to dismiss VC2 in a similar way to how you brought it up in the first place, just animate it back off the screen, remove it from the view, then release it (unless you released it when you showed it). Alternatively you could use the built-in methods,

```
presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

and

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
```

which have their own animation.

Comment: Franklyn: i am not loading any new ViewController. it's already loaded in appdelegate. i am animating VC1 from VC1 itself. when i animate VC1 from VC2, it's not working

Comment: Your code shows you are indeed loading a new VC1 from VC2 - if this:
ViewController1 *view_control = [[ViewController1 alloc]init];
[self.navigationController popSlideViewController:view_control];
...is what you're doing, you're trying to "pop" a VC whose view you haven't even added yet.

Comment: Maybe you could post more code, including the appDelegate stuff

Comment: popSlideViewController (not confused with popViewControllerAnimated) is my custom function that i added in category class..

Comment: But your code shows that you're creating a new instance of VC1, then trying to dismiss it without having added its view. (I think whether or not you're using a custom function here is irrelevant) The new instance of VC1 is NOT the VC1 whose view you added earlier.

Comment: i am adding an instance of VC1 which is assign it to rootViewController..so i think, i don't need to addSubview.